# How to create factories with existing relationship on model in MIKRO-ORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, mikro-orm

Hi I am trying to figure out how to create factory and define relationship between models.

For example I have UserFactory with User entity and this entity has connection to userType table. In factory I have not access to EntityManager so I couldn´t find any existing.

```
export class UserFactory extends Factory<User> {
  model = User
  definition(faker: Faker): Partial<User> {

    const user = {
      firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
      lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
      ...
      userType: // Here I need do something like this:
                // EntityManager.findOne(UserType, {id: 1}}
                // But EntityManager is private in Factory class
    }

    return user
  }
}
```

Itried also something like this but this return me an error:
**ValidationError: Value for User.type is required, 'undefined' found**
DatabaseSeeder

```
export class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

  async run(em: EntityManager): Promise<void> {

    const users: User[] = new UserFactory(em).each(async user => {

      const userType : UserType| null = await em.findOne(UserType, 1)
      console.log(tenant)

      const userType = await em.findOne(UserType, 1)
      if (userType !== null) {
        user.type = userType
      } else {
        user.type = em.create(UserType, {
          type: 'test'
        })
      }

    }).make(10)

  }
}
```

What is the proper way to achieve this please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shared seeder context as describer in the docs:

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/seeding#shared-context

```
export class AuthorSeeder extends Seeder {
  async run(em: EntityManager, context: Dictionary): Promise<void> {
    // save the entity to the context
    context.author = em.create(Author, {
      name: '...',
      email: '...',
    });
  }
}

export class BookSeeder extends Seeder {
  async run(em: EntityManager, context: Dictionary): Promise<void> {
    em.create(Book, {
      title: '...',
      author: context.author, // use the entity from context
    });
  }
}
```

I guess this shared context should be also available in the seeder factories, but you can always handle this yourself, as both the seeder and factory is your implementation, so you can pass any additional options in there. Its you who initializes the factory so I dont think there is a better way than doing it in your code.

I would suggest not to `flush` and `findOne` things in your seeder, you should aim for a single flush and use the shared context instead for entity look up.